# SQL: how to rank events within a cohort by time

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm working with a Postgres table named `orders` that looks like this:

```
user_id   product   order_date
1     pants         7/1/2022
2     shirt         6/1/2022
1     socks         3/17/2023
3     pants         2/17/2023
4     shirt         3/13/2023
2     pants         8/15/2022
1     hat           4/15/2022
5     hat           3/14/2023
2     socks         12/3/2022
3     shirt         4/15/2023
4     socks         1/15/2023
```

Here is a dB Fiddle with the data:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uNGjP7gpKwdPGrJ7XmT7k3/0

My goal is to output a table that shows the *sequence* of a customer's orders.  For example, customer 1 first purchased a hat, then purchased pants, and finally purchased socks.

Here is the desired output:

```
user_id   first_order   second_order    third_order
1     hat           pants           socks
2     shirt         pants           socks
3     pants         shirt           <null>
4     socks         shirt           <null>
5     hat           <null>          <null>
```

I used `RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY order_date) AS rank` to arrange the sequence of the orders by `user_id`.  This works in "long" form.  However, I'm not able to translate this into the form of the table above.

How would I do that?

Thanks for your help,
-Rachel

Answer (score 0):

You can use a series of `left join`s on a subquery with the ranks. Your joining criteria can be to `join` the relation on both the user name and an incremented rank number. This way, rank `2` rows are joined onto rank `1` rows for a given user, and so on:

```
with cte as (
   select o.*, rank() over (partition by user_id order by order_date) r from orders o
)
select c.user_id, c.product, c1.product, c2.product from cte c
left join cte c1 on c1.user_id = c.user_id and c1.r = c.r + 1
left join cte c2 on c2.user_id = c.user_id and c2.r = c1.r + 1
where c.r = 1
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9P01bL8h).

Comment: Multiple self-joins on the CTE might end up less efficient than the "canonical" approach using conditional aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using the conditional aggregation, the `group by` operator, the case statement, and the aggregation function `max()`:

`rank()` will function as intended if the combination (user_id, order_date) is unique; otherwise, `row_number()` should be used.

In the event that a user orders twice a day, one of the products will be skipped since the rank of the two orders will be the same.

```
  SELECT
    *
    , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY order_date) AS rank
FROM
    orders
    
GROUP BY
    user_id
    , product
    , order_date
)
select user_id, max(case when rank = 1 then product end) as first_order,
                max(case when rank = 2 then product end) as second_order,
                max(case when rank = 3 then product end) as third_order
    
from cte
group by user_id
```

[Demo here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/Vv3VgfD4CL8vJ1uhozJWQ/0)

Comment: What is the benefit of ` select * … group by …` in the CTE ? It looks like an anti-pattern, while it seems like order rows have no duplicates.

Comment: `rank()` might produce ties (if a user ordered twice on the same day) - in which case one number will be skipped, meaning that one of the output columns *could* end up `null`.

Comment: Good remark @GMB, `row_number()` is the best choice to ignore the case of having orders twice on the same day

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions to enumerate the orders of each user, then pivot with conditional aggregation. In Postgres, which supports the standard `filter` clause of aggregate functions

```
select user_id,
    max(product) filter(where rn = 1) product_1,
    max(product) filter(where rn = 2) product_2,
    max(product) filter(where rn = 3) product_3
from (
    select o.*,
        row_number() over(partition by user_id order by order_date) rn 
    from orders o
) o
where rn between 1 and 3
group by user_id
```